# Having error 400 when creating several textBox when pressing a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 2 sheets (one to place the data and another for options).
The one with the data it has some buttons (at row 1), some textBox and DropBox (at row 2) and at row 3 are the headers of the table with all the data below.

The sheet with the options for the moment has only one button to recreate the menu (the TextBox and DropBox at row 2 in the data sheet)

However when pressing the button to run the macro it gives error 400 with no description and a red x signal. Sometimes it gives error when re-creating and first textBox, sometimes the second or third as well (never the fourth or the fifth).

Why does such 400 error happen ? What causing it ?
[image: error 400]

When trying debug the code i placed some `Debug.Print` in some places and after running 3 times (after clicking in button 3 times this is the output in the immediate window.

```
-----------Running createMenu-----------
TextBox5 DIM done
TextBox5 Set done
TextBox6 Delete
-----------Running createMenu-----------
TextBox5 Delete
TextBox5 DIM done
TextBox5 Set done
TextBox6 DIM done
TextBox6 Set done
TextBox7 Delete
-----------Running createMenu-----------
TextBox5 Delete
```

The code below (the one to recreate the menus) is placed in the data worksheet.

```
Sub createMenu()
    Debug.Print "-----------Running createMenu-----------"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Dados1")
    With ws
        .Range("A2").NumberFormat = "0"
        .Range("B2").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        .Range("C2:D2").Merge
        .Range("C2:D2").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        Call newTextBox(.Range("E2"))
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Call newTextBox(.Range("F2"))
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Call newTextBox(.Range("G2"))
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Call newTextBox(.Range("H2"))
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Call newTextBox(.Range("I2"))
        Call newDropBox(.Range("J2"), "=Opções!A1:A14")
        Call newDropBox(.Range("K2"), "=Opções!B1:B2")
        .Range("A2:N2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End Sub
Sub newDropBox(t As Range, list As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Dados1")
    With ws.Range(t.Address).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=list
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
Sub newTextBox(t As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Dados1")
    With ws
        Dim OLEObj As OLEObjects
        If .OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Dim x As Integer
            For x = 1 To .OLEObjects.Count
                If .OLEObjects(x).Name = "TextBox" & t.Column Then
                    .OLEObjects(x).Delete
                    Debug.Print "TextBox" & t.Column & " Delete"
                End If
            Next x
        End If
        Dim myTextBox As OLEObject
        Debug.Print "TextBox" & t.Column; " DIM done"
        Set myTextBox = .OLEObjects.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        Debug.Print "TextBox" & t.Column; " Set done"
        With myTextBox
            .Name = "TextBox" & t.Column
            .LinkedCell = t.Address
            .Left = t.Cells.Left
            .Top = t.Cells.Top
            .Width = t.Cells.Width
            .Height = t.Cells.Height
            .Object.BackColor = 16777152
            .Object.BorderStyle = 1
            .Object.BorderColor = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So i find out the reason ...
So when i am doing the for loop he started by finding (lets say 2 OLEObjects).
If the in the first cycle of the loop the wanted object is found he delete one of the objects making it the total OLEObjects count to less 1.
There for when cycling to the second OLEObjects he will not find it, and throw such 400 error.

So the fix i done was exit the loop when the target OLEObjects is found.

```
Sub newTextBox(t As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Dados1")
    With ws
        Dim OLEObj As OLEObjects
        If .OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Dim x As Integer
            For x = 1 To .OLEObjects.Count
                If .OLEObjects(x).Name = "TextBox" & t.Column Then
                    .OLEObjects(x).Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next x
        End If
        Dim myTextBox As OLEObject
        Set myTextBox = .OLEObjects.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With myTextBox
            .Name = "TextBox" & t.Column
            .LinkedCell = t.Address
            .Left = t.Cells.Left
            .Top = t.Cells.Top
            .Width = t.Cells.Width
            .Height = t.Cells.Height
            .Object.BackColor = 16777152
            .Object.BorderStyle = 1
            .Object.BorderColor = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```